# Android number picker set sensitivity for scroll

Tags: android, android-number-picker

I am trying to use a time picker in my alarm clock. My current lowest level api is set to 17 so I cant just use the time/date picker and set the style to spinner because this is only available in api 21.

I found this library:

https://github.com/KasualBusiness/MaterialNumberPicker

I have been able to format for 2 digits and get it to function exactly as a time spinner. The only thing is the sensitivity. For me to swipe from 0 minutes to 59 minutes it take 13 swipes which is arduous and impractical.

The library is based on Android number picker and I have been able to change the formatting using a number picker formatter:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html

I have not been able to find a way to increase the the sensitivity of the scroll.

Thanks in advance for you help

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?